# How to open multiples ".DOC" without ".DOCX" files in MS Word from command prompt

Tags: windows, cmd, directory

When using:

```
dir /s /b *.doc | findstr /v .doc
```

or

```
dir /s /b *.doc
```

Display me a list of `.DOC` files, well, i need to open this files in MS Word without `.DOCX`. I try it with the following command:

```
for /f "delims=" %a IN ('dir /s /b *.doc
| findstr /E ".doc"') do call start winword "%a"
```

But it also opens files with `.DOCX` extension,
what is the right way to do it?

Comment: The line-break does not appear in your actual script, right? because it would not work then; furthermore, the pipe needs to be escaped like `^|`... Then you should add the `/L` switch to `findstr` to force a literal search string, and also `/I` to do a case-insensitive search...

Comment: Ok, thank you, i don't know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filenames longer than 8.3, for instance "File.docx", are shortened by Windows as FILE~1.DOC and such files meet *.doc mask as well. Try this:

```
for %g in (*.doc) DO @if /I "%~xg"==".doc" call start winword "%g"
```